# Javascript syntax function issue

Tags: javascript, function

Why does the following code work shouldn't title be set to lowercase causing the second if statement to fail?

```
var title = 'RANDOM_LETTERS';
if(title.toLowerCase() == 'random_letters')
{
     //This will fire
}

if(title == 'RANDOM_LETTERS')
{
      //This will still fire as the variable was not saved to lowercase
}
```

Comment: Strings are ***immutable***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't changing the value of the variable. You can prove it by printing out the value of the variable at each step.

```
var title = 'RANDOM_LETTERS';

console.log(title);
// Here, title is "RANDOM_LETTERS"

if(title.toLowerCase() == 'random_letters')
{
    console.log(title);
    // Here, title is still "RANDOM_LETTERS"
}

console.log(title);
// Here, title is "RANDOM_LETTERS"

if(title == 'RANDOM_LETTERS')
{
    //We get to this line, our title is still "RANDOM_LETTERS"
}
```

According to the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), the value of the string using this method is not affected.

Comment: so its just saying take this variable make it lower case and compare but dont change the actual value of the variable.

Comment: Yup. According to the docs (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa989676(v=vs.80).aspx), it returns a new string, and does not modify your existing string. Other languages may very well modify your existing string through pointers, but Java is entirely pass by value (get ready for a good ol' stackoverflow argument).

Comment: okay so its passing a value not a reference i think i get it now

Comment: Correct; when you call title.ToLowerCase(), you get a whole new string (memory has been allocated for this string). You also have a piece of memory for "title". If you wanted to store the value of title.toLowerCase(), you should do title = title.toLowerCase().

Comment: Oh, crap. I noticed this was tagged as javascript, not java. Same concepts apply, but I will edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase. The docs specifically say "toLowerCase() does not affect the value of the string str itself."

Comment: Because strings are immutable in JS. This is the correct answer